# Keeping time in a bell choir

Tags: time-signatures

How do I keep time when I don’t play all the notes (bell choir).  I’m a beginner and have never played an instrument. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

First figure out what time signature the song is in. (4/4 and 3/4 are the most common).

This will tell you how many beats to count for each measure (3 beats or 4 beats for 3/4 and 4/4 respectively).

Next find the main pulse (this is what you would tap your foot to if you were just listening along.)

Tap your foot to the pulse (or beat) and count in your head the correct number of beats per measure.

If you are counting for more than a measure it helps to use the downbeat to indicate how many measures have passed, for example: to count 4 bars of 4/4 I could count like this:

**1**, 2, 3, 4 | **2**, 2, 3, 4 | **3**, 2, 3, 4 | **4**, 2, 3, 4 ||

Things you can try at home or in the car, or wherever:

- Listen to the radio and tap along to the beat.
- count along and figure out if the song is in 4 or 3 or something else
- try to learn the section name of the songs (verse, chorus, bridge, etc) this will help you understand the form of the song and give some structure to the song overall.
- see if you can find out how many measures (4 counts or 3 counts) are in each section (hint it will be 4, 8, 12, or 16 most of the time)
- ask your "band mates" for help. musicians love to share and teach and learn from each other. lean on that if needed.

have fun, you will find that making music is just about the best thing ever!